# Add necessary library files during runtime when using cucumber in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, amazon-dynamodb, cucumber

We are using Cucumber in our development process in building a service in AWS. We are using DynamoDb and when we are running tests locally we are using a local instance of DynamoDb. To do this we need to include in the classpath certain library files. We have manged to do this for the test task of gradle but not for the cucumber task

Given that these files are in a folder `build/dyanamodb-local` in our project, is there a way to include them in the classpath of the cucumber task?

The build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'checkstyle'
    id 'pmd'

}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    maven { url "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dynamodb-local-frankfurt/release" }
}


def jacksonVersion = "2.10.3"
def jupiterVersion = "5.6.0"
def awsSdkVersion = "1.11.791"

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
apply plugin: 'pmd'

configurations.testImplementation.canBeResolved = true
configurations {
    cucumberRuntime {
        extendsFrom testImplementation
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-lambda-java-core', version: '1.2.0'
    implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-lambda-java-events', version: '2.2.7'
    implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-lambda', version: awsSdkVersion
    implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-dynamodb', version: awsSdkVersion

    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jdk8', version: jacksonVersion
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: jacksonVersion
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module', name: 'jackson-module-parameter-names', version: jacksonVersion

    implementation group: 'com.github.BIBSYSDEV', name: 'nva-commons', version: '0.3.5'

    testImplementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'DynamoDBLocal', version: '1.12.0'
    testImplementation group: 'com.almworks.sqlite4java', name: 'sqlite4java', version: '1.0.392'

    testImplementation group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-java', version: '5.6.0'
    testImplementation group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-picocontainer', version: '5.6.0'
    testImplementation group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-junit', version: '5.6.0'
    testImplementation group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter', version: jupiterVersion
    testImplementation group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest', version: '2.2'
}

task copyNativeDeps(type: Copy) {
    from(configurations.testImplementation) {
        include "*.dylib"
        include "*.so"
        include "*.dll"
    }
    into 'build/dynamodb-local'
}

test.dependsOn copyNativeDeps
test.doFirst {
    systemProperty "java.library.path", 'build/dynamodb-local'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    failFast = true
    testLogging {
        events 'skipped', 'passed', 'failed'
    }
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}

task cucumber() {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = "io.cucumber.core.cli.Main"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime+ configurations.testImplementation + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            args = ['--plugin', 'pretty', '--glue', 'features', 'src/test/resources']
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I mixed the classpath and the library-path. What I needed, was to edit the library path. If one needs to edit the classpath however, I would suggest to look at the solution provided by @madhead

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have a configuration for Cucumber, like in the docs:

```
configurations {
    cucumberRuntime {
        extendsFrom testImplementation
    }
}
```

Then just add a folder to the configuration like:

```
dependencies {
    cucumberRuntime(fileTree('build/dyanamodb-local'))
}
```

It should do the trick.

Instead of polluting your dependencies, consider using [amazon/dynamodb-local](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/dynamodb-local) Docker image or [LocalStack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack).

Comment: Thanks :) The dependency alternative did not work. I will consider the rest of the solutions

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by adding systemProperties in the `javaexec` configuration of the cucumber task. The cucumber task is now the following:

```
task cucumber() {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = "io.cucumber.core.cli.Main"
            systemProperties =[ "java.library.path" :'build/dynamodb-local']
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime+ configurations.testImplementation + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            args = ['--plugin', 'pretty', '--glue', 'features', 'src/test/resources']
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not "classpath", that's a library path :(

Comment: Thanks for bringing it to my notice.I edited the initial question for clarity.